# tinysort jquery sort on two items

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, sorting, jquery-plugins

I want to sort by both the distance and name.

```
(id) ----name----  ----distance----
  1     store           2
  2     shop            3
  3     market          1
  4      bazaar         2

#view
<ul id="xanim">
    <% @objects.each do |obj| %>
        <li><h3><%= obj.distance %></h3><%= obj.distance %>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Using tinysort (http://tinysort.sjeiti.com)

```
#javascript
var $Ul = $('ul#xanim');
$Ul.css({position:'relative',height:$Ul.height(),display:'block'});
var iLnH;
var $Li = $('ul#xanim>li');
$Li.each(function(i,el){
    var iY = $(el).position().top;
    $.data(el,'h',iY);
    if (i===1) iLnH = iY;
});
$Li.tsort('h3:eq(0)',{order:'asc'}).each(function(i,el){
    var $El = $(el);
    var iFr = $.data(el,'h');
    var iTo = i*iLnH;
    $El.css({position:'absolute',top:iFr}).animate({top:iTo},500);
});
```

I have the sort down fine when just going by one column (eg. just by distance orders it: market, store, bazaar, shop). However, if both distances are equal, I want to also sort by name (eg. distance and then name: market, bazaar, store, shop).

How can I sort by secondary component if the first ones are equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a stable sorting algorithm (http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Stable_Sort). First sort by your secondary component (name), then by the primary component (distance). The stable sort will ensure that elements with the same distance are still sorted by name.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple sorting is not yet possible in tinysort. But it will be: http://code.google.com/p/tinysort/issues/detail?id=23

someday :/